# Solution for decomposing/avoiding Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

As far as I know, there are two options to deal with Many-to-Many relation in a relational database (MySQL, MariaDB) and object-relational database (Postgres)

Common scenario:

---> A Product appears(has) many bills

---> A bill has many products

===> Product (n) ------> (n) Bill

I've googled to find a way to decompose Many-to-Many and here is my result:

1. Create a lookup table that takes 2 Product_ID and Bill_ID as foreign keys to decompose the Many-to-Many relationship into two One-to-Many. This is fine for both relational and object-relational database
2. Take advantage of object-relational database data type such as an array, JSON, etc. For example, add product_ids as an array of an integer into Bill table and vice versa (Like this tutorial: http://blog.bguiz.com/2017/postgres-many2many-sql-non-relational/)

So I tried to seek another solution and I found this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175894/mutually-exclusive-many-to-many-relationships/175908#175908

But it seems unclear to me

So I was wondering any others solution for the object-relational database (Postgres)? any keywords?
I really appropriate your help
Thank you

Comment: Well, data integrity is harder to maintain when using JSON/Arrays, when I care about it prefer relational :-)

Comment: option 1 is the very normal one and provides integrity, as mentioned in the comment above. Is there a problem with using it? It's not really clear what your objective is. Why do you feel you need an alternative solution?